# onchange select(dynamic) dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding `select` dropdown and an input field(which is currently disabled) dynamically. I want to get that whenever `Others` option is selected, the input field should be enabled. Here is my code:-

```
<div></div>
<button> Add</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        option_html = '<option value="Others">Others</option><option value="Others1">Others1</option>'
        input_html = '<input placeholder="Other, if any" class="form-control input-md others_input" type="text" disabled="disabled">'
        html = '<select class="form-control select_question" name="qa_">' + option_html + '</select>' + input_html
        $('button').on('click', function(){
            $("div").after(html);
        })

        $('select.select_question').on('change', function(){
            alert(111)
            $(this).closest(".others_input").prop('disabled', false);
        })
    })
</script>
```

I'm not able to catch the onchange event. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0zoejqs/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate:

```
$("#container").on('change',".select_question",function(){
   $(this).next(".others_input").prop('disabled', this.value!="Others");
})
```

I want it to trigger the change when loaded to enable the others immediately

I use .html instead of .after which is what you meant I am sure. After will add the select AFTER the div instead of inside the div

```js
$(function(){
  $("#container").on("change","select.select_question",function(){
    console.log(this.value)
    $(this).next(".others_input").prop('disabled', this.value!="Others");
  });

  option_html = '<option value="Others">Others</option><option value="Others1">Others1</option>'
  input_html = '<input placeholder="Other, if any" class="form-control input-md others_input" type="text" disabled="disabled">'
  html = '<select class="form-control select_question" name="qa_">' + option_html + '</select>' + input_html
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $("#container").html(html);
    $("#container select.select_question").change();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button> Add</button>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the jsFiddle link. It's not catching the onchange event.

Comment: `closest` would not work here. You need different selector as the elements are siblings not parent-child.

Comment: `<select>` element is added dynamically. And, the selector is catching the element before the element exist in DOM. This won't work

Comment: @Adam- Exactly. That's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Updated to use delegation

Comment: Its not working. It gets enabled even on `Others1` option as well. If `Other` option is selected, it should get enable, else for any other option, it should get disable.

Comment: Please try again. It works perfectly for me and it enables the field because Others is the default selection - If you copy to your own code, then you need to give the ID to the div

Answer (score 0):

You are using `closest` in wrong way as `input` is not parent of the `select` but comes next to it.

Moreover, `select` element is binded dynamically, so you need to use delegated event handling syntax:

```js
$(function(){
  option_html = '<option value="Others">Others</option><option value="Others1">Others1</option>'
  input_html = '<input placeholder="Other, if any" class="form-control input-md others_input" type="text" disabled="disabled">'
  html = '<select class="form-control select_question" name="qa_">' + option_html + '</select>' + input_html
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $("div").after(html);
  })

      $(document).on('change', 'select.select_question', function(){
            alert(111)
            $(this).next(".others_input").prop('disabled', !this.value=="Others");
        });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button> Add</button>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the jsFiddle link. It's not catching the onchange event.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I copied your code for testing in jsfiddle. :( Sorry

Comment: @mplungjan Works fine for me in Chrome as well. May be I don't know correct way of getting a new link from JSFiddle. I updated code in OP's linked Fiddle, hit update button and copied the link from the address bar.

Comment: @mplungjan I told you sir, I copied the first bit, where the only thing you can say is copied is `!this.value=="Others");` Otherwise that's an obvious thing. (I upvoted your question for that ;) ) . After that, why do you think I should copy anything from your code or suggestion?

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I am still having issues since I forked the jsfiddle instead of creating a new one

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj- Its not working. It gets enabled even on `Others1` option as well. Kindly check your jsfiddle link. :)

Comment: @mplungjan I tried using Code Snippet. Enabling works fine. I get double set of select and input tags though :(

Comment: @mplungjan :) Sorry, didn't check that. Will fix it now.

Comment: If `Other` option is selected, it should get enable, else for any other option, it should get disable.